# Excel VBA get address of selected multi rows

Tags: excel, vba

How to get the address of selected multi rows?
When I press CTRL and multi select the specific rows, the result is will selected all the rows start from 1st specific row to last specific row, the rows I didn't select will be selected together if they are in 1st row to last row range.

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Selection
MsgBox (rng.Address)
```

Picture added

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain how the rows you didn't select will be selected together? Your code works fine. What do you want it to do that it doesn't do? To select multiple rows you need to press Shift, not Ctrl. Please explain your question.

Comment: Ctrl+click can select specific rows, I need is specific multi rows address. They separate and not together.

Comment: `Selection.Address` will give you their address.

Comment: Cannot, Selection.Address will take all rows address, include the rows I didn't select.

Comment: What, exactly, are you selecting? Entire rows? Partial rows? Table rows? Individual rows of any of the 3 kinds? Or groups of rows of any of the three kinds?

Comment: I was added the picture to question, just normal select the row like picture and get their row address

Comment: `Selection.Address` will give you the address of all selected rows and cells. Try typing `? Selection.Address` or `MsgBox Selection.Address` in the Immediate pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my Answer:

```
    For DelRowAddr = 0 To i - 1
    For RngProcAddr= 0 To j - 1 'The range only can delete the row
        If ArrDelRow(DelRowAddr) = ArrProcRow(RngProcAddr) Then
            DelTargetMatch = DelTargetMatch + 1
        Else: Dismatch = Dismatch + 1
        End If

        If Dismatch = j Then 'Out of range
            MsgBox DataFSC.Range("B5").Value & ArrDelRow(DelRowAddr), vbOKOnly + vbInformation, DataFSC.Range("A5") 'Error message in other sheet because some language can't show in vba
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next RngProcAddr
    Dismatch = 0
Next DelRowAddr

Dim StrArrDelRow As String
        StrArrDelRow = ""

If DelTargetMatch = i Then 'Maybe it is only the way to delete the row that I selected only
        For DelRowAddr = 0 To i - 1
                If DelRowAddr = i - 1 Then
                    StrArrDelRow = StrArrDelRow & Range(ArrDelRow(DelRowAddr)).Address
                Else: StrArrDelRow = StrArrDelRow & Range(ArrDelRow(DelRowAddr)).Address & ","
                End If
        Next DelRowAddr
        
    If Not StrArrDelRow = vbNullString Then
        If Range(StrArrDelRow).Row = DeleteProcessOther.TopLeftCell.Row Then
            MsgBox DataFSC.Range("B5").Value & ArrDelRow(DelRowAddr - 1), vbOKOnly + vbInformation, DataFSC.Range("A5")
            Exit Sub
        Else: Range(StrArrDelRow).EntireRow.Delete 'If I use this way to delete, it wont delete row5,7 as picture show
        End If
    Else: MsgBox DataFSC.Range("B5").Value & ArrDelRow(DelRowAddr - 1), vbOKOnly + vbInformation, DataFSC.Range("A5")
            Exit Sub
    End If

MsgBox ("¡Ì Deleted!") 'some special symbol or character can't show in vba
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

On excel under developper step, u can save a macro.

```
Range("1:12,19:19,23:23,26:26").Select
Range("A26").Activate
t = Range("1:12,19:19,23:23,26:26").Address
```

t="$1:$12,$19:$19,$23:$23,$26:$26"
This is the result after select multi rows
$1:$12 => lines 1 to 12
$19:$19=> one other line selected

split t by , with a for each

in the loop split by :
...

Comment: I need is vba get the cells address, not fix the cells address in vba.

Comment: sorry I forget one line, I updated my code

Comment: Okay, I will try using loop to find selected cells, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want to achive but I think the answer will be in here:

```
Option Explicit


Sub split_multi_address()
  ' note because the question asks about a selection on a sheet,
  ' fully qualified range names are not used
  ' as safe to assume we only want to operate on activesheet


  Dim s As String
  s = Selection.Address
  
  Dim arrSplitStrings() As String

' array of range addresses as string
  arrSplitStrings = Split(s, ",")
  
  Dim v As Variant
  For Each v In arrSplitStrings
    Debug.Print v
  Next v
  


' array of ranges

  Dim arrSplitRanges() As Range
  ReDim arrSplitRanges(UBound(arrSplitStrings) - LBound(arrSplitStrings))
  Dim i As Long
  i = 0
  
  ' create array of ranges
  For Each v In Split(s, ",")
    Set arrSplitRanges(i) = Range(v)
    i = i + 1
  Next v
  
  ' print array of ranges
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrSplitRanges) - LBound(arrSplitRanges)
    Debug.Print arrSplitRanges(i).Address
  Next i
  
  

' array of ranges rows
  ' redim to remove previous values
  ReDim arrSplitRanges(UBound(arrSplitStrings) - LBound(arrSplitStrings))
  i = 0
  
  ' create array of range rows
  For Each v In Split(s, ",")
    Set arrSplitRanges(i) = Range(v).EntireRow
    i = i + 1
  Next v
  
  ' print array of ranges
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrSplitRanges) - LBound(arrSplitRanges)
    Debug.Print arrSplitRanges(i).Address
  Next i


End Sub
```